# How can I optimize this Query? which retrieves the value of a column

Tags: mysql, optimization, query-optimization

How can I optimize this query in MySQL? Retrieving the municipality from the province? TIA

```
select DISTINCT PM.municipality, count(*)
from anReference as R
inner join anFieldInfo as F on R.ref_id = F.ref_id
inner join tblProvince as PP on F.province_id = PP.province_id
inner join tblMunicipality as PM on F.municipality_id = PM.municipality_id
WHERE R.category = 0 AND R.test = 1
AND PP.region_id=2
AND PM.province_id=7
AND R.date_accessed between '2016-11-01 00:00:00' and '2016-11-30 23:59:00'
GROUP BY PM.municipality;
```

Here's what I got when I run EXPLAIN.[image]

Comment: Performance questions should include EXPLAIN ANALYZE and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. Slow is a relative term and we need a real value to compare. MySQL Also Please read [How-to-Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: How do I edit my question to include explain? Thanks

Comment: there is an edit link just below the question

Comment: one step closer: but __Performance questions should include EXPLAIN ANALYZE and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. Slow is a relative term and we need a real value to compare. MySQL Also Please read [How-to-Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
__ please do read the how to ask link

Comment: Ok, nevermind. I'll figure it out myself. Thanksanyway.

Comment: Ok, nevermind. I'll figure it out myself. Thanksanyway.

Comment: Ok, nevermind. I'll figure it out myself. Thanksanyway.

Comment: Remove `DISTINCT`, is it redundant with `GROUP BY` (which you do need).

Comment: Are the counts too high?  That is a common problem when doing `JOIN` + `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting inflated values, then consider rewriting something like:

```
SELECT PM.municipality, count(*)
    FROM PM
    WHERE tblMunicipality AS PM.province_id=7
      AND EXISTS ( ... )
    GROUP BY PM.municipality
```

Where the subquery (in `EXISTS`) is the `JOINs` of all the other tables.

An aside:  This is a 'simpler' way to test a month's range:

```
AND R.date_accessed >= '2016-11-01'
AND R.date_accessed  < '2016-11-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```